# I want to create a procedure that print multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to create a procedure that prints out multiple values but I don't know how. Even if I declare the Select statement inside the procedure it gives error.

This is my table
Student(ID_student, ID_faculty, Name, Mark)

My excercise consist on creating a procedure that display all the names of students with mark grater than 7.5.

My code gives error on creating the procedure

```
set serveroutput on;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getStudent
 (
  s_name OUT DBUSER.USERNAME%TYPE
 )

IS

BEGIN

  SELECT name
  INTO s_name,
  from Student WHERE mark > 7.5;

  dbms_output.put_line(s_name)

END;
/
```

Comment: Your immediate problem is probably the comma at the end of `INTO s_name`.  It is helpful to specify the actual error you are receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following table.

```
create table student ( id_Student varchar2(100) , id_faculty varchar2(100), name varchar2(100), Mark varchar2(10) );
```

with the following data

```
REM INSERTING into STUDENT
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into STUDENT (ID_STUDENT,ID_FACULTY,NAME,MARK) values ('1','2','jon smith','8');
Insert into STUDENT (ID_STUDENT,ID_FACULTY,NAME,MARK) values ('2','3','lucy smith','10');
Insert into STUDENT (ID_STUDENT,ID_FACULTY,NAME,MARK) values ('4','5','james smith','8');
Insert into STUDENT (ID_STUDENT,ID_FACULTY,NAME,MARK) values ('6','7','al bundy','6');
Insert into STUDENT (ID_STUDENT,ID_FACULTY,NAME,MARK) values ('8','9','george jackson','10');
Insert into STUDENT (ID_STUDENT,ID_FACULTY,NAME,MARK) values ('10','11','penelope smith','9');
```

procedure

```
create or replace procedure get_student as 
begin

FOR rec IN (SELECT name
  from Student WHERE mark > 7.5) 
   LOOP 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (rec.name); 
   END LOOP; 

end get_student;
```

to execute procedure simply.

```
BEGIN
  GET_STUDENT();
--rollback; 
END;
```

Comment: thank you very much for your response, but how can I try to execute it now? Should it be inside a pl/sql block?

Answer (score 0):

`INTO` can assign a single value to the variable. Your query must be giving more than 1 rows. also there is a syntax error.

You can use the following code which will return single record using `ROW_NUMBER()` with the highest mark. If you want to return all the students with marks greater than 7.5 then out parameter should be `cursor` or `varchar2` with comma-separated values

```
set serveroutput on;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getStudent
 (
  s_name OUT DBUSER.USERNAME%TYPE
 )

IS

BEGIN

  SELECT NAME INTO S_NAME FROM   
  (SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by mark desc) AS RN
  from Student WHERE mark > 7.5);

  dbms_output.put_line(s_name);

exception WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
s_name := NULL;

END;
/
```

Cheers!!